# Stochastic Domination between Binomial Random Variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

> Assume that $X$ is Bin$(n, p)$ and that $Y$ is Bin$(m, q)$. Under which conditions on $(n, m, p, q)$
>   does the property that $X \preceq Y$ hold?

I know that if $n \leq m$ and $p=q$, then  $X \preceq Y$, as can be proved using a coupling argument considering $n$ and $m$ Bernoulli random variables.

But 
I don't know how to tackle the problem when both $n$ and $p$ can vary.

Comment: Obviously, the condition $[n\leqslant m]$ is necessary, $[n\leqslant m,p\leqslant q]$ is sufficient, $[n\leqslant m,np>mq]$ is impossible, remains to study the case  $[np\leqslant mq,p>q]$. Any idea?

Comment: How's the condition $n \leq m$, $np > mq$ impossible? For example, given some $n$ and $m$ such that $n \leq m$, we can take $p$ and $q$ such that  $np > mq$. Take $n=10$, $m=20$, $p=1/2$, and $q=1/5$.

Comment: @Did why is the condition $n \leq m$ necessary? Can we have $n>m$ such that there exists some $p$ and $q$, $p < q$ which makes $X \preceq Y $?

Comment: No, because if $n>m$, for every nonzero $p$ and $q$,  then $P(X\geqslant m+1)>0$ and $P(Y\geqslant m+1)=0$, which contradicts the condition that $P(X\geqslant x)\leqslant P(Y\geqslant x)$ for every $x$.

Comment: "How's the condition n≤m, np>mq impossible?" Of course the condition is "possible", but it implies that $X\preceq Y$ does not hold.

Comment: Okay. That helped! I'll try to write a formal solution! Thanks!

Comment: Theorem 1a of https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.528.9213&rep=rep1&type=pdf has the answer I think.